# Can't boot Android device after replacing system.img

Tags: android, image, boot

I am working on a custom android device using the i.MX53 board from NXP (formerly Freescale). I have the OS source code, various intermediate files, and the final resulting files once produced by another developer (who customized the OS, but has since left our company). I now need to modify the contents of the system partition on these devices. I have attempted to build and load a new system.img file using make_ext4fs.exe and the directory which contains the original collection of files the prior developer must have used. I believe I have created a nearly identical system image, as the one previously used. They are both ext4, 200MB.

There is a utility for this board (called MfgTool) which copies and mounts images automatically for you at the click of a button. That MfgTool successfully writes my image to the device. When I try to boot, however, it fails and just loops with the custom boot image being displayed. If I swap out the new system image and restore the prior one in this process, everything works again. So it has to simply be a matter of getting this system image built correctly.

What might be the cause? What difference in the images might cause this? Is it possible there is a signature needed, or some other kind of protection which I'm failing to account for?

Comment: If the custom boot image (I'm assuming the normal android logo has been replaced) is shown, there's a good chance Logcat is up and running. Can you connect to the device and see what is reported?

Comment: I can't adb into it.  Everything I see indicates that is enabled, but I don't see a way to interface with the device other than via this MfgTool.  I do have the source for that, so I guess I can dissect that if need be.

Comment: Is there another common way to view logs / debugging output?

Comment: And yes, the custom logo for my company is displayed rather than the stock Android image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my primary problem was that I need to set the mount point for the image to "system" NOT "/system" when it was created via make_ext4fs despite all documentation out there to the contrary!  I figured this out by carefully reading the ASOP source:  ...build\tools\releasetools\img_from_target_files.

Of note, after this hurdle, I ran it another problem where the device was acting funky.  That turned out to be the result of not having any symbolic links in the image.  It seems like at the least you normally have symbolic links directing your "bash" commands to the toolbox binary in system/bin.  I don't know how you normally get those, but creating those links and then bundling them into the image fixed that.  I suggest checking the bin directory for symbolic links if you manually create a system image like this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace one of the system image service executable with a shell that dump kmsg and logcat to a file (in data partition or external storage for example) and then call the original executable. Then, boot to your previous system and collect those logs.

Comment: This is a trick which I've also used successfully. But I wouldn't dump the output into /data/local/tmp - that location is frequently cleared out on a successful boot. Anywhere else in /data should be OK.

Comment: That's sounds like a great suggestion!  Thanks!  I'll give that a try.

Comment: Any suggestion which service to add the wrapper to?  Does it make sense to do this on the system image if that image is the one with the problem?

Comment: Search your init.*rc file for a non critical service. And do it on the problematic system image, that's the point :)

Comment: I'm not an expert in Android architecture, so excuse me if this is nube question, but does bootanimation display my boot logo?  I can see that is displayed, so thought maybe I could tap into what I know is executing successfully?

Comment: That MfgTool I'm using formats all the partitions.  So I'm not sure where I can write to and then have it persist.  I have external an flash drive that it could go to but I'm not sure how to access it.  It seems like that drive is detected and hooked into by an app launched after this boot process.  Any guidance how I could write to that from the NDK C rather than via the Java I have as a reference?

Comment: Boot your previous system image, connect your external storage and find its device ( probably under /dev/block/... ). Then, on the shell script in your new system image, mount that device and direct your logs to that mount point.

Comment: I've just noticed there are 2 different logos displayed during the boot process.  There is a static one, and an animated one.  I don't get past the static one, so I probably don't make it to bootanimation binary?